# is Authentication tag always appended at last to ciphertext in AES-GCM 256?

Tags: encryption, aes, gcm

I am using AES GCM 256 to encrypt/decrypt a UUID string,We are using java 7 + bouncy castle library for this,We are getting authentication tag of 128 bit ,i am confused ,whether it's position is always at the last or not.

Ex:-

Plain text :- **a7d80af9-6386-48ff-b9b6-71ad80257b34**

IV :- **PKBlbi3htx1PLdOx**

Cipher Text : **PKBlbi3htx1PLdOxMnEbJHN8DSP7wksgm86XWRCTU6a78drESnrnl30XteEqMy9/H/hD+7PGXTOyPz1rQjM0tA==**

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that RE350. I'm answering so many questions that I completely forgot about that one. Sometimes I'm even Googling up my own answer to a question :P

Comment: I've expanded the answer for you with regards to the AEAD RFC.